# How to get a graphics-method, such as paint, to activate on a button-click

Tags: java, button, graphics, paint

For a school-project, we've recieved a set amount of figures we're supposed to paint on a canvas with the normal Java-graphics method .paint(). This is supposed to be controlled with the help of a few buttons, each painting a different mix of colors. The paint-method is quite easy and works but when we try to connect the buttons, nothing happens but the buttons appearing on the screen. The code reads as following:

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class MarcusErikaGrf2 extends Applet implements ActionListener {

    Button knapp, knapp2, knapp3, knapp4, knapp5;
    boolean svart=false, rod=false, gul=false, gron=false, rensa=false;
    int tx[],ty[],pox[],poy[],pgx[],pgy[],pgxf[],pgyf[],bx[],by[],bxf[],byf[],hf[],hy[];
    Polygon txy, po, pg, pgf, b, bf, hxy;

public void init (){

    this.setSize(800,900);
    this.setBackground(Color.white);
    this.setLocation(200,1);

    knapp= new Button ("Svart");
    knapp2= new Button ("Röd & Rosa");
    knapp3= new Button ("Gul & Orange");
    knapp4 = new Button ("Grön & Blå");
    knapp5 = new Button ("Rensa fönstret");

    knapp.addActionListener(this);
    knapp2.addActionListener(this);
    knapp3.addActionListener(this);
    knapp4.addActionListener(this);
    knapp5.addActionListener(this);

    add(knapp);
    add(knapp2);
    add(knapp3);
    add(knapp4);
    add(knapp5);

    int tx[] = {375,475,425};
    int ty[] = {110,110,250};
    int pox[] = {65,120,120,65,50};
    int poy[] = {350,350,450,450,400};
    int pgx[] = {35,88,98,88,35,25};
    int pgy[] = {210,210,270,330,330,270};
    int pgxf[] = {36,87,97,87,36,26};
    int pgyf[] = {211,211,270,329,329,270};
    int bx[] = {372, 400, 395, 420, 415, 440/*TP*/, 415, 400, 405, 382, 387 };
    int by[] = {60 , 67 , 70 , 77 , 80 , 87 /*TP*/, 95, 88 , 85 , 75 , 70};
    int bxf[] = {373,399,394,419,414,439,416,401,406,383,388};
    int byf[] = {61,67,70,77,80,86,94,88,85,75,70};
    int hx[] = {150,185,225};
    int hy[] = {176,120,176};

    Polygon txy = new Polygon(tx,ty,tx.length);
    Polygon po = new Polygon(pox,poy,pox.length);
    Polygon pg = new Polygon(pgx,pgy,pgx.length);
    Polygon pgf = new Polygon(pgxf,pgyf,pgxf.length);
    Polygon b = new Polygon(bx,by,bx.length);
    Polygon bf = new Polygon(bxf,byf,bxf.length);
    Polygon hxy = new Polygon(hx,hy,hx.length);

}

@Override
public void paint(Graphics g){

    if(svart == true){
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.drawRect(50, 50, 30, 150); //Rektangel 1
    g.drawRect(90,50,30,150); //Rektangel 2
    g.drawOval(140, 60, 40,30); //Öga 1
    g.drawOval(200, 62, 40, 30); //Öga 2
    g.fillOval(147,67,15,15); //Pupill 1
    g.fillOval(218,69,15,15); //Pupill 2
    g.fillOval(310,100,50,120); //Svart oval, Stor 
    g.fillOval(310, 50, 22, 30); //Svart oval, Medium
    g.fillOval(270, 220, 20, 28); //Svart oval, Liten
    g.drawOval(100,230,140,40); //Rosa oval, outline
    g.fillOval(370,250,100,50); //Svart oval, horisontell
    g.drawRect(200,300,180,150); //Grön rektangel, outline
    g.drawRect(170,369,10,130);
    g.drawRect(140,369,10,130);
    g.fillOval(250,480,28,40);
    g.fillOval(400,480,14,20);
    g.drawOval(280,520,122,200);
    g.drawOval(160, 570, 80, 100);
    g.drawOval(50,680,140,40);
    g.drawRect(65,500,65,150);
    g.drawPolygon(pg);
    g.drawPolygon(b);

    g.setColor(Color.white);
    g.fillOval(317, 65, 8, 8); //Vit prick i svart oval, Medium
    g.fillOval(277, 235, 6, 6); //Vit prick i svart oval, Liten
    }

    else if(rod == true){
    g.setColor(Color.red);
    g.fillOval(161,571,79,99);
    g.fillOval(255, 150, 50, 70);

    g.setColor(Color.pink);
    g.fillOval(101, 231, 138, 38); //Rosa oval
    g.fillPolygon(bf);

    g.setColor(Color.white);
    g.fillOval(255, 170, 50, 50);
    }

    else if(gron == true){
    g.setColor(Color.blue);
    g.fillRect(51, 51, 29, 149); //Rektangel 1
    g.fillRect(91, 51, 29, 149); //Rektangel 2
    g.fillRect(66,501,64,149);
    g.fillPolygon(txy);

    g.setColor(Color.green);
    g.fillRect(201, 301, 179, 149); //Grön rektangel
    g.fillOval(51,681,139,38);
    g.fillPolygon(pgf);
    }

    else if(gul == true){
    g.setColor(Color.yellow);
    g.fillRect(171,370,9,129);
    g.fillRect(141,370,9,129);
    g.fillOval(281,521,120,198);

    g.setColor(Color.orange);
    g.fillPolygon(po);
    g.fillPolygon(hxy);
    g.fillOval(150, 160, 45, 45);
    g.fillOval(180, 160, 45, 45);
    }

    else if(rensa == true){

        repaint();

    }

}

public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e){       

    if(e.getSource() == knapp){
        svart = true;
    }

    else if(e.getSource() == knapp2){
        rod = true;
    }

    else if(e.getSource() == knapp3){
        gul = true;
    }

    else if(e.getSource() == knapp4){
        gron = true;
    }

    else if(e.getSource() == knapp5){
        rensa = true;
    }

  }

}
```

What are we missing?

Answer (score 0):

In your actionPerformed(...) method you need to invoke:

```
repaint();
```

This tells the component to repaint itself.

```
else if(rensa == true){
    repaint();
}
```

Never invoke `repaint()` from within a painting method. A painting method is for doing the painting, not scheduling the painting.

Comment: Yeah, we added the repaint() after all of the if-methods in the actionPerformed(...), forgot to do it before we posted here though. However, it still doesn't work, it only paints one of the colors and then the rest of the buttons go inactive